# convert JSON to TSV using pandas

Tags: json, pandas, csv

I would like to convert JSON to TSV but not from a file or to a file.

```html
messages = {
    "1":[
        {
            "id":"4d9edf9b-ab9a-45bc-a453-3ea9ecc97818", 
            "message":"m1",
            "access": "*"
        },
        {
            "id":"7c4b41e4-3e4f-40ed-9aa4-3854a6b3706a", 
            "message":"m2",
            "access": "*"
        },
        {
            "id":"c1c332cf-7cb4-4c5e-bf85-3d7ae3a11625", 
            "message":"m3",
            "access": "*"
        }, 
        {
            "id":"dc9b47b9-d325-475d-9994-a4269faa0873", 
            "message":"m4",
            "access": "*"
        }
    ]
}




> import sys
> import pandas as pd
> table = pd.read_json(messages[1], orient='records')
> table.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep='\t', index=False)
```

I tried something like this but it did not work.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

To convert the list of Json into DataFrame you should

```
 table=pd.DataFrame.from_records(messages["1"])
```

then save as you did in the post .